# SSLHandshakeException when connecting through internet

Tags: android, https, proxy, ssl-certificate, android-volley

In my android app I can connect to this url with local wifi without any problem:

```
https://didgahmobile.chargoon.net/
```

However when I try to connect through internet for example using mobile data or connecting through proxy, I get `SSLHandshakeException` in android app. Also both desktop and mobile chrome browsers show the message `"Your connection is not private"`.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I've checked server firewall and there is no restriction on IP address.

I also have a little different situation with another `https` url address. In that case, After the first time that I connect through local wifi, I can connect through proxy or mobile date, but connecting after fresh install or clear data with mobile data or proxy throws same `SSLHandshakeException`.

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this if you're usign android 7, because you must add some configuration:

```
<network-security-config>  
      <domain-config>  
           <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourDomain.com</domain> 
                             <!-- like: didgahmobile.chargoon.net -->  
           <trust-anchors>  
                  <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->  
                  <certificates src="system" />  
                  <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->  
                  <certificates src="user" />  
           </trust-anchors>  
      </domain-config>  
 </network-security-config>

<application
        android:name="yourappname"
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Source: [Trusted certificates](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html)

Comment: I have this problem in all android versions. However I used this solution and it didn't solve the problem on android 8 and earlier. Thanks.